# Accessing data member of RootViewController in another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

I am developing an iPhone application using Objective-C. I want to access a data member which is of type NSMutableArray of the RootViewController class in another class. I tried making the array static. But I would like to have a non static array. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need two things:

1. a reference to the `RootViewController`
2. a means of getting your variable out of `RootViewController`.

In a situation where you have (most likely) one `RootViewController` per application, it makes sense to keep a reference to that object in your application's delegate. You can get the app delegate like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

In your app delegate class you should add a property called `rootViewController` that exposes your `RootViewController` object. Now you can write things like

```
RootViewController *theRootViewController = appDelegate.rootViewController;
```

This satisfies the first requirement. Now, in order to access the object owned by the view controller, you'll need to add a property to `RootViewController`. You didn't really say what the object is or does, so let's just call it `myMutableArray`. Create a `readonly` property with that name on `RootViewController`, and now you'll be able to write things like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = theRootViewController.myMutableArray;
```

This will let you do what you want to do.

I have to warn you, though: exposing an `NSMutableArray` is generally not a great idea. The reason is that if you change the contents of that array, `RootViewController` will have no idea that you've done this. So if you were creating, say, a master-detail view, your `RootViewController` would not know that you've added a new object.

It would be better if you wrote methods that let `RootViewController` modify the array internally. For example, you could have a method named `addFooObject:` that manages the array. Then the view controller will know what you've done to it. For access, you could very easily return an immutable, autoreleased copy of the mutable array from your property.

Comment: Don't forget to import your appdelegate class (#import "AppDelegate.h") :)

Comment: Oh and i needed to typecast the app delegate: 

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Answer (score 5):

You can also access the root view controller uising the SharedApplication in one line of code:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]
```