# Get default view object of the app to invoke methods on?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In the viewController class I want to make a draw method that adds an UIImageView to the main view as a subview. Now how do I get the View object from the app so that I can invoke the draw method on that specific view in the method of another class. Also Where in the code is the view instantiated that pops up on my iphone when I start the app by default?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting a more firm grasp of views and view controllers in the docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH1-SW2

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

But, if you need to access the view from your viewController, it's as simple as accessing the view property:

`[myViewController.view addSubview:someOtherView];`

Regarding your question about where the root view is instantiated, it depends on whether or not you're using a XIB to design your interface.  If you want to modify the view controller's view in code, override the view controller's `viewDidLoad` and make sure you call `[super viewDidLoad]` first.

If you want to select a different view controller at startup, you can do so in the app delegate in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions` since this is where the app assigns its window and rootViewController properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative response. Could you please also explain how I can access a viewController Object? From what I have gathered from the second link that you posted, the ViewController handles all the graphical elements of the applications. I want the ViewController to have a draw method with parameters that take the reference of a UIIMage and say a CGRect for instructions where and how to draw it. So then in my ClassB file I could go  [myViewControllerObject draw: myIMage]. So 1. Does this work? 2. Is this an alright way of doing it, or Is this a really stupid practice:p?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696360/accessing-data-member-of-rootviewcontroller-in-another-class

But I would say the best way would be to create your own subclass of the view controller you're using and create a method on your view controller to handle adding the UIImageView.  Another way would be to have ClassB members in your view controller that are instantiated by the view controller.  It's really dependent on what you're trying to do in a larger context though, so I can't give you a very specific answer.

Comment: No problem!  If you're interested in game programming, this guy has some great tutorials: 

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials